# Mapinfo: Color label by attribute-expression

Tags: labeling, mapinfo

It can be done in QGIS, but how to do that in Mapinfo?. I need to classify the labels color by  attributes from a column.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm not easily! and not without MapBasic or a lot of work to the best of my knowledge.

How many attribute types do you have? If there are only a few you could query each attribute, add the result to the map, and style the labels accordingly.

Aside from that the only other way that I thought of would be to effectively do the same thing, but use MapBasic and loop through each of the attributes, add it to the map, style it and move to the next one.

Comment: Hi Morgan. Approximately 300. I had the same ideas as the ones you are mentioning. Not an easy solution for that no.

Comment: Yeah sorry, limitation of MI Pro me thinks.

Comment: 300 different colours!!?? That might be hard to distinguish on the screen or ?